# How can a.prototype.b.c() get instance of a?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can a.prototype.b.c() get the instance of a?

I know I can do a.b.c.call(a), but there are too many methods, and it is  terrible if I have to type .call every time.

```js
const a = function() {
    this.name = "I'm A";
}
const b = {
    name: "I'm B",
    hello() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

a.prototype.$app = b;
const c = new a();

c.$app.hello.call(c); // I know this work, and show me "I'm A"
c.$app.hello(c); // this show me "I'm B", but I expect it show me "I'm A"
```

I can modified b = {} and a.prototype.$app = b this two places only.

**Update**

Actually I would like to achieve something like:

```
Vue component(
    methods: {
        someMethods() {
            this.$app.hello() // hello can access vue instance.
        }
    }
)
```

So I can have a $app SCOPE for all my custom method, in all vue-router base instance, without mixin to insert them in all instance...

Comment: c.$app.hello(**c**)

You are not using the c argument there I think

Comment: The value of `this` when you call `c.$app.hello()` will be `c.$app`, and that object has its own local "name" property.

Comment: `hello` is "a method" of `b` if you want it to be a method of `a` instances you could do `a.prototype = b` or `a.prototype = Object.create(b)` then you could call it `c.hello()` without manually passing the context or binding or injecting context via argument.